# How do I display Hdfs directory path throgh solr search as an output? Suppose if user search in solr then I want to display the path that directories?

Tags: hadoop, solr, lucene, hdfs, solrj

I have written a code in JAVA for search through solr it gives particular document. But now I want to show the directory where the data is stored as an output to a user. 
If user searches for a keyword I want to show user that in which directory their data is stored.

Comment: are you indexing or storing the directory path in the solr document..?

Comment: I am indexing the data

Comment: In order to show the data you need the same to be stored..if you have your schema.xml then modify the same and add store='true' for the same field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a (complicated) workaround  : retrieve the name of the shard used by adding "fl=*,[shard]" to your request. You can from there know the name of the core with the core.properties file in the shard's directory. The index data will be stored in hdfs under the core's name.

However, this does look like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).